# Vaadin: get data from applet

Tags: java, applet, vaadin

I integrated my applet with vaadin but i can't get data by applet. 
It returns String field and i want to put this in textbox in vaadin window. 
Does anybody make something like this?  in this example used httpURLconnection. Is it one way?

[example](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/88)

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more what you have tried to do.

Comment: I only tried to use HttpURLConnection, because i have only one example with applet integration.